# JQuery to change div when link created from mysql data is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a navigation bar that is created from a MySQL table. I want to click on the link and only change the contents of two divs on the page. However, I cannot figure out the proper way to write the jQuery code.

I've attempted to include a single class for all the links and use

```
$(".class").click(function(){
//the code to change the div
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

PHP code

```
<?php

    require(__DIR__.'/dbconf.php');
    require(__DIR__.'/db_functions.php');

    $db_con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pass, $dbname); 

    $column = "playerName";
    $table = "Players";
    $condition = "";
    $key = "";

    $query = selectData($db_con, $column, $table, $condition, $key);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

        $res[] = $row[$column];

        echo "<a href = # class = 'player' name ='".$row[$column]."'>".$row[$column]."</a>";
    }

    mysqli_close($db_con);
?>
```

JQuery code

```
$(".player").click(function(){
    var player = $(this).val()

    var dataString = 'playerName'+ player;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "coin_amount.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(postresult){
            $(".coins").html(postresult);}
    });
    return false;
    });
```

It seems like this should work. That when any link with the class "players" is clicked, it should change the value of the player variable and call the coin_amount.php file. But it doesn't. What am I not understanding? I do know the ajax function is correct because I call that function on page load and it works. So it has to be something in the click function.

Comment: is `.player` created dynamicly with ajax?

Comment: Hang on. My PHP code was truncated. I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: Ok. I fixed that. The player class is added through the PHP script but it is not created dynamically.

Comment: What is the html output?

Comment: Enable mysqli error reporting.

Comment: Your `echo` statement doesn't have a valid HTML code. Remove spaces and add quotes for the `href` tag.

Comment: I'm not sure how to share my html output. I've made the changes suggested below and fixed the echo statement, but it's still not doing anything at all.

Comment: Ok. I have a much, much larger problem than I thought I did. And I don't even know how to go about asking for help. For some reason this function is pulling data from another function even though I've changed variable names. Is there somewhere that I can post my entire code and ask for help? I don't want to take up your time since it seems to be a basic misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: This could be a good start: change var player = $(this).val() to var player = $(this).attr('name')

Comment: Thank you. It took a combination of many different suggestions (so I don't know how to mark one as right.) But I got it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If player is created after the DOM has loaded, you will have to attach the click listener to the document, like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.player', () => {
  // execution code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ADD It in the `<script></script>` tag in the head of page after have loaded the jquery library

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#cercaButton").click(function () {
                        $(".divClass").load("./action/loadDdtGiornalieri.php");
                    });
                });
```

In your case add the id at the link tag generated from the php code that print the menu.

I suggest you to add different ID at every link of the menu in order of load different contenent
From php you have to generate a string as

```
    <a id="cercaButton">Cerca</a>
```

This is a complete example of load, including also the parameter post at the php web page
If you have to post data at the page loaded from jquery simplest code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#cercaButton").click(function () {
                    $(".divClass").load("./action/loadDdtGiornalieri.php", {
                        dateIn: $("#dateIn").val(),
                        tipoInterrogazione: $("#tipoInterrogazione").val()
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: I don't want a button. I want to be able to click the player name and have the output change inside the div. And I have the document.ready(function) in my file.

Comment: Thanks. But I think I have a bigger problem than I thought I did and I have no idea how to ask for help. Yikes.

Comment: @KristenMiller Think carefully about how to request it. Exist a way for require every things:
Yestearday for formulate my question I wrote the post for 3 hours.
If you think this is the correct answer at this question set is please ;-)